# SQL Server 2005 - Columns to Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Pretty new to SQL and I have looked at several of the answers to what I think is the same issue as I'm currently struggling with.
Most of them reference a Pivot functionality but I can't figure out if that's what I need or even how to make it work. (I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2005)

Basically I have a tabel with a Key and some Plants and the output is like below:

```
Key  |  Plant
-------------
12   |  123
12   |  456
12   |  789
13   |  456
13   |  789
14   |  123
14   |  456
14   |  789
14   |  012
14   |  345
15   |  123
15   |  456
```

I'm trying to get my output to display the data like:

```
Key  |  Plant
-------------------------------
12   |  123, 456, 789
13   |  456, 789
14   |  123, 456, 789, 012, 345
15   |  123, 456
```

The number of plants will vary greatly, but I'd like to have the Plant(s) displayed in the Plant column as a string of the plant(s) connected to the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `PIVOT` function for this.  A *pivot* will convert the plant rows into separate columns.

To get the result that you want you can use `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select distinct t1.[key],
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t2.plant
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.[key] = t2.[key]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') plant
from yourtable t1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab31c/2)

Comment: I might be doing something wrong - because I get an error (Error in WHERE clause near '('. Unable to parse query text.) - or maybe I'm just a bit to green still :) Maybe it's important to say that the data is contained in the same table - I'm not sure if that's an issue? Well, I've put in data like: SELECT DISTINCT ttTable.[Key],
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ttTable.Plant
         FROM ttTable
         WHERE ttTable.[key] = ttTable.[key]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') Plant
FROM ttTable;
With the above error message as result

Comment: My bad - helps if I turn off Diagram and Criteria pane - thanks for the assistance - really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   t1.[Key],
   STUFF(
            (SELECT ', ' + t2.Plant
            FROM yourtable t2
            WHERE t1.[Key] = t2.[Key]
            FOR XML PATH( '' )),
         1, 2, '' )
FROM yourtable t1
GROUP BY [Key]
```